# Site Header visible based off scrollTop and scrollUp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, elementor

In my web page, I have a **header** which should disappear when I go down 100px and appear when I go up 50px.

I wrote this script but it doesn't seem to work

**CSS**

```
/* CSS will only work on screens larger than 1024px */
@media (min-width: 1024px){
 #site_header {
  display:none; 
  width:100%!important;
 }
}
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

       //Decides when this script will work 1024
      if ( $ (window).width() > 1024) {

       //How far down does the user has to scroll 100px
        if ( $ (window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $ ('#site_header').fadeOut();

          } else {

           if ( $ (window).scrollUp() >= 50) {
            $ ('#site_header').fadeIn();
             }
      }
    });
});
```

**Update** I put the [link](https://www.iheartelementor.com/how-to-hide-your-header-till-user-scrolls-down/) where I found and copied the code that will help you understand.

basically what i want is **reverse** the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/rok4Lwz5/18/

**HTML**

```
<div id="site_header"></div>
<div id="siteBody"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS will only work on screens larger than 1024px */
@media (min-width: 1024px){
 /*#site_header {
  display :none; 
 }*/
}

#site_header {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;

  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

#siteBody{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;

  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;

  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript + jQuery 3.3.1**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
console.log('document ready');

 jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {

    console.log($(window).width());
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    // console.log($(window).scrollUp());

  // if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
          console.log('hide');
        $('#site_header').fadeOut();
    } else {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
        console.log('show');
        $('#site_header').fadeIn();
      }
    }
  // }

 });
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks you so much ! 

do you think it's possible to add a code to change the color of the text when scrolling and when it's at the very top  ?